# workbox 3 - ignore URL params on run-time caching

Tags: javascript, service-worker, offline-caching, workbox

I want to cache assets from a secure CDN that uses policy token as URL params.
for example: `www.cdn.com/image.png?Policy=AAAAA&Key-Pair-Id=BBBBB`
and if I re-visit the site, I want to get the asset from the cache even if I have a different policy token and Key-Pair-Id.
for example: `www.cdn.com/image.png?Policy=CCCCC&Key-Pair-Id=DDDDD`

If I use this code in the service worker:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /^(http(s)?:)?\/\/www\.cdn\.com.*/,
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate()
);
```

It doesn't find the response in the cache and goes to the network.
I want it to match by the URL without the URL params (even if Policy=CCCCC&Key-Pair-Id=DDDDD is not actually a valid policy). just look if `www.cdn.com/image.png` exists and retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this by using a custom handler:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /^(http(s)?:)?\/\/www\.cdn\.com.*/,
    ({url, event}) => {
        return caches.open(`${prefix}-${runtime}-${suffix}`).then((cache) => {
            const customRequest = `${url.origin}${url.pathname}`;
            return cache.match(customRequest).then((cacheRes) => {
                if (cacheRes) {
                    return cacheRes;
                }
                return fetch(event.request).then((fetchRes) => {
                    cache.put(customRequest, fetchRes.clone());
                    return fetchRes;
                });
            });
        });
    }
);
```